# Progression where nth term repeats n times.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to deal with sequences like 
$$1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,........$$ Now they don't come under any specific sequence (A.P., G.P. or H.P.). Can we deduce any simple formula or working method to deduce their $n^{th}$ term and the sum upto $n^{th}$ Any kind of hint would certainly work.

Comment: You could try [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C4), which offers 52 such sequences.  You probably want [A002024](http://oeis.org/A002024) or something close to it

Comment: When does the number $k+1$ occur in the sequence for the first time? After $k$ is exhausted, which occurs after $k-1$ is exhausted.  So you can find the formula when a particular number  makes its first and last appearance in this sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each number $ n > 1$ appears for the first time in the sequence after $ \sum_{k<n} k$ iterations. Meaning that n will appear for the first time at $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1$ th term and will appear for the last time at $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
So in order to deduce the kth term, you must find a certain $n$ that satisfies 
$ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1 \leq k \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ 
For the sum , once you find your $n$ , we can easily deduce that we are actually summing the squares of natural numbers, up to (n-1), and adding $n$,$ k- \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ times
Hence, the $S(k) = \sum_{i < n } i^{2} + n * (k-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}) $ where $ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1 \leq k \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $

Answer (score 1):

What is wanted
is a function such that
$f(n+1)-f(n) = n$
so that each term
is $n$ further.
You then want to find
the inverse of this function
to get the value.

An obvious choice is
$f(n) = n(n-1)/2$.
To find the inverse,
solve
$y = x(x-1)/2$
for $x$.
You can use the quadratic formula
(in $x^2-x-2y = 0$)
or note that
$8y = 4x^2-4x
=(2x-1)^2-1
$
so
$x = \dfrac{1 \pm\sqrt{8y+1}}{2}
$.
Since this has to be positive,
the positive root is required,
so
$x = \dfrac{1 +\sqrt{8y+1}}{2}
$.

Finally,
we need the integer part,
so
$x = \bigg\lfloor\dfrac{1 +\sqrt{8y+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor
$.

As a check,
here are the values
for $y$ from 0 to 20:

{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}